# AVAssetExportSession progress not updating

Tags: swift, avassetexportsession

I make use of `AVAssetExportSession` to export movies to MP4 format using the codes below:

**Step 1: User clicks a button to start conversion**

```
@IBAction func clickConvert(_ sender:UIButton) {
    self.convertProgress?.progress = 0
    self.convertProgress?.isHidden = false

    var preset = AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
        switch self.qualitySelection?.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            preset = AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
            break
        case 1:
            preset = AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
            break
        case 2:
            preset = AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
            break
        default:
            break
    }


    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
        let fileName = formatter.string(from: Date()) + ".mp4"

        let convertGroup = DispatchGroup()
        convertGroup.enter()

        do {
            let documentDirectory = try self.fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
            let filePath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            if(self.videoURL != nil) {
                self.convertVideo(fromURL: self.videoURL!, toURL: filePath, preset: preset, dispatchGroup: convertGroup)
            } else {
                print("nil Video URL")
            }
            convertGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
                // reset Convert button state
                self.convertButton?.titleLabel?.text = "Convert"
                self.convertButton?.isEnabled = true

                self.delegate?.updateFileList()
                // Take back to old VC, update file list
                if let navController = self.navigationController {
                    navController.popViewController(animated: true)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Trigger convert video function**

```
func convertVideo(fromURL: URL, toURL: URL, preset:String, dispatchGroup: DispatchGroup) {
    let outFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    let inAsset = AVAsset(url: fromURL)
    let startDate = Date()

    AVAssetExportSession.determineCompatibility(ofExportPreset: preset, with: inAsset, outputFileType: outFileType, completionHandler: { (isCompitable) in
        if !isCompitable {
            return
        }

        guard let export = AVAssetExportSession(asset: inAsset, presetName: preset) else {
            return
        }
        export.outputFileType = outFileType
        export.outputURL = toURL
        export.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        let start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, preferredTimescale: 0)
        let range = CMTimeRangeMake(start: start, duration: inAsset.duration)
        export.timeRange = range

        // Timer for progress updates
        self.exportTimer = Timer()
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            print("start exportTimer")
            self.exportTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.05, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                let progress = Float(export.progress)
                print("Export Progress: \(progress)")

                self.updateProgressDisplay(progress: progress)

                if progress < 0.99 {
                    let dict:[String: Float] = ["progress": progress]
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(Constants.Notifications.ConvertProgress.rawValue), object: nil, userInfo: dict)
                }
            })
        }

        export.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
            // Handle export results
            switch export.status {
                case .exporting:
                    print("Exporting...")
                    self.updateProgressDisplay(progress: export.progress)
                    break
                case .failed:
                    print("Error: %@!", export.error!)
                    break
                case .cancelled:
                    print("export cancelled")
                    break
                case .completed:
                    let endDate = Date()
                    let elapsed = endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
                    print("Elapsed: \(elapsed)")
                    print("successful")
                    self.exportTimer?.invalidate() // Stop the timer
                    self.generateThumbnail(path: toURL)
                    break
                default:

                    break
            }
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    })
}
```

However, status update is not working, as the timer `exportTimer` never fires (attempt 1), and the `exportSession.exporting` case never fires (attempt 2).

p.s. The video can be converted without any problem

p.s. the Notification has been added in `viewDidLoad()` as follow:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidReceiveConvertProgress(_:)), name: Notification.Name(Constants.Notifications.ConvertProgress.rawValue), object: nil)
```

Status update functions (both attempts) are as follow:

```
@objc func onDidReceiveConvertProgress(_ notification:Notification) {
    print ("onDidReceiveConvertProgress")
    if let data = notification.userInfo as? [String:Float] {
        print("Progress: \(String(describing: data["progress"]))")
        self.convertProgress?.progress = data["progress"]!
    }
}

func updateProgressDisplay(progress: Float) {
    print("updateProgressDisplay")
    self.convertProgress?.progress = progress
}
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you figured this out, but just in case someone else try your code, the problem why the progress timer is not firing is because you missed two things.

1. You never called the function to start the timer. e.g. self.exportTimer.fire()
2. You have to make sure to update this timer on the main Queue.

I had the same problems and doing these two things fixed my issue.